# Kendo UI - Binding to remote data, shift the location of bars

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

We would want to hide the space(s) between bar charts, as in attached, if we have any key value is 0, the next bar should shift to left automatically for that series, seems like there is no direct configuration to achieve it.

Just to brief you more, if you see the example of Kendi UI Bar Chart at http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/remote-data-binding, spain-electricity.json always have the data for all the keys, just to reproduce the scenario, you may assume the **year 2000** object as given below:

```
    {
    "country": "Spain",
    "year": "2000",
    "unit": "GWh",
    "solar": 62206,
    "hydro": 0,
    "wind": 42206,
    "nuclear": 62206
}
```

Here you see, the value of hydro is 0, due to that, we see the blank space between 2 bars, as it doesn't generate anything, that's what we want to reduce, in order to give better experience.

Technically wind bar should be next to nuclear.

[image]

Comment: The chart is a generated svg element with fixed paths as bars. You can't easily work on it changing positions and properties. It's no like css. Consider the alignment you would have to adjust and perhaps redraw all other series'/bars' positions. It is no that simple, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, we have checked with Telerik, this feature isn't available at the moment.